# What is the best way to check of an object is an Enum in Cython?

Tags: python, enums, cython

I am looking for a Cythonic way (yes, Cython) to check if an object is of type Enum.  Specifically, I want to distinguish between ints and IntEnums.  I am looking for something like:

```
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    bint PyObject_TypeCheck(object obj, PyTypeObject* type) nogil

PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &PyEnumType_Type)
```

But, is there something like PyEnumType_Type defined anywhere?

Comment: You should have, at most, one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular old `isinstance(obj, Enum)` works fine in Cython as well, but does it have good performance?  Maybe I am overthinking this.

Comment: You are overthinking it. If you look at the generated C code for this it'll be a fairly efficient `PyObject_TypeCheck` or similar. I wouldn't put it in a fast inner loop if possible, but it's basically fine

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it works and is the simplest and most reliable answer to the original question.  The ```getattr()``` technique is a good way of solving my original problem of distinguishing between int and intEnum in Cython, but would register as True for anything with a ''name" attribute.

Comment: You also probably want to use `IntEnum` instead of `Enum` in your `isinstance()` check.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found what I am looking for.  There is a `PyEnum_Type` defined in cpython/include/enumobject.h.  I will try the following:

```
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    PyTypeObject PyEnum_Type
    bint PyObject_TypeCheck(object obj, PyTypeObject* type) nogil

PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &PyEnum_Type)
```

Comment: `enumobject.h` has nothing to do with `Enum`.  `Enum` only exists as Python code.

Comment: OK, @EthanFurman.  Do you have a recommendation on how to distinguish between an int and a IntEnum object passed to a function in Cython?

Answer (score 0):

Yet a third way that does not require importing Enum into Cython.

`if getattr(val, 'name', None) is not None`